# No puedo instalar Vectorbt ni en Spider, ni en JupiterLab

Tags: python

alguien me puede ayudar?

Al instalar la librería VectorBT me sale este mensaje en la consola:

Attempting uninstall: llvmlite
Found existing installation: llvmlite 0.34.0
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

No hay manera que pueda arreglarlo, alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Puedes googlear, hay varias respuestas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766671/cannot-install-librosa-python-how-can-i-uninstall-llvmlite

Answer (score 0):

> utiliza Vscode para tus proyectos en python, espero que sirva esto:

1. Instala Python activando el path.
2. Instalar la librería con el comando `python -m pip install vectorbt` o si utilizas linux `pip install vectorbt`

> Esto debería de funcionar link de la [Librería](https://pypi.org/project/vectorbt/)